# Python Tkinter: Canvas can't overrides other elements

Tags: python, tkinter

I want the Canvas component (`c`) in Tkinter to overwrite other elements in the window. After searching, I try to use `c.lift()` and `c.tag_raise()`, but it can't solve my problem. What shall I do?

```py
import tkinter as tk

window = tk.Tk()
window.geometry('300x300')

def show():
    c.place(x=80, y=80, width=140, height=140)
    c.lift()

c = tk.Canvas(window, bg='white')

bt1 = tk.Button(window, text='show Canvas', command=show)
bt1.place(x=110, y=135)

tk.mainloop()
```

In fact, in my program, `bt1` and some other elements must be created after `c`.

Thanks!

Comment: This is a bug in `Canvas` - the normal `.lift()`/`.lower()` methods are overridden by Canvas-specific methods (properly referred to as `tag_raise` and `tag_lower`) that are for rearranging items drawn on the Canvas, rather than the Canvas itself.  You could do `btn1.lower()` instead - or use `tk.Misc.lift(c)` to bypass the bug and directly access the proper `lift` method.